# Can't find Windows boot manager in bios

Tags: boot, windows-10, bios, boot-repair

I recently installed Ubuntu by dualbooting it on my windows laptop now windows boot manager is missing in bios and Ubuntu is showing up. I have to access windows by grub bootloader. Please help me to get back windows bootloader in my bios.

Comment: Most likely there is no Windows any more. How did you install Ubuntu?

Comment: I dual booted it. But i can access windows from my grub menu, it is listed in grub but not in my computer bios.

Comment: So what is the problem? Use grub to load Windows.

Comment: Is there any way to get back my windows bootloader in my bios

Comment: BIOS or UEFI? If BIOS, you have to boot Windows from grub menu. If UEFI, you can boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu. But grub only boots working Windows, so fast start up must be off and Windows must not need chkdsk. So we can see details of your install. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair